# Check fields for null entry and change field background to lightyellow?

Tags: c#, null, field

Great website - very helpful in my C# Class.

I am trying to write a method in C# that will Check fields for null entry and change field background to LightYellow?

The form is a display form that views records in a SQL database.

Here is what I tried - but the variable for the field names isn't translating to the field name.

Advice?

```
    // YellowBack Method fills background of key fields that are missing data or are NULL
    private void YellowBack()
    {
        //Bool fieldContents = true;
        string fieldVariable;
        string[] fieldName = { "activity_TitleTextBox", "act_Title2TextBox", "kid_NotesTextBox", "review_AdultTextBox", 
     "phoneTextBox", "addressTextBox", "cityTextBox", "websiteTextBox", "weblink_TextTextBox",
     "hoursTextBox", "admissionTextBox" };
        int count = 0;


        //Check each field name
        for (int index = 0; index < fieldName.Length; index++)
        {
            fieldVariable == fieldName.Text;


            if (fieldVariable.Trim = "")
            {
                fieldVariable.BackColor = LightYellow;
            }
            else
            {
                fieldVariable.BackColor = Window;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the index . . . . you should be using something like:

`fieldVariable = fieldName[i].Text;`

I also think that you won't be able to set the property `BackColor` on `fieldVariable` as it is a string.  You should probably be using the object grid or text control that your database binds to and setting the color properties of that . . . but I'm not sure there's enough information here to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're looping through a list of strings and trying to make the string into a TextBox control. Instead, you should probably loop through all the controls on the form, and for each one that is a TextBox, see if it's name matches a name in your list. Then you can set the back color of the control based on the Text property.

There are other problems with your code also, like in your `if` statement you are doing an assignment (`=`) instead of a comparison (`==`).

Here's what I would do:

```
private void HighlightEmptyFields()
{
    // Create a list of all the text box names that we want to examine
    var textBoxNames = new List<string>
    {
        "activity_TitleTextBox", "act_Title2TextBox", "kid_NotesTextBox", 
        "review_AdultTextBox", "phoneTextBox", "addressTextBox", "cityTextBox", 
        "websiteTextBox", "weblink_TextTextBox", "hoursTextBox", "admissionTextBox"
    };

    // Loop through every control on the form
    foreach (Control formControl in this.Controls)
    {
        // Find the groupbox control by name
        if (formControl.Name != "groupBox1") continue;

        // We found the group box, so loop through every control in it
        foreach (Control groupBoxControl in formControl.Controls)
        {
            // Try to cast the control to a TextBox.
            var textBoxControl = groupBoxControl as TextBox;

            // If the cast fails, move on to the next one...
            if (textBoxControl == null) continue;

            // Now we have one a textbox control, so see if the
            // textBoxNames array contains the name of this text box.
            if (textBoxNames.Contains(textBoxControl.Name,
                StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // We found a match, so set the backcolor based on Text property
                if (textBoxControl.Text.Trim() == "")
                {
                    textBoxControl.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                }
                else
                {
                    textBoxControl.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }

        // Since we found the control we were looking for, we can stop looking
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The names are correct - ran the new code - same effect.  I notice the other textboxes are all inside groupbox's - so that is somehow affecting their readability?

Comment: Pulled the a Textbox out of the groupbox and it works perfect!

Any idea how get at it in the groupbox?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Sure, it's very similar. Just search for the groupbox instead, and when you find it, do the same kind of loop through all the groupbox controls. I updated the example to search for a groupbox named "groupBox1". It should work if you change that to the name of your groupBox. Play around with it...